# eslint-loader webpack es2015 parse error

Tags: webpack, babeljs, eslint

My webpack eslint config :

```
  eslint: {
    configFile: ".eslintrc",
    emitWarnings: true
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loaders: [
          require.resolve('react-hot-loader'),
          require.resolve('babel-loader'),
          require.resolve('eslint-loader')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
```

My error :

```
ERROR in ./src/scripts/main.jsx
Module parse failed: /Users/alexandre/Documents/developpement/piemapping/apple-pie/node_modules/react-hot-loader/index.js!/Users/alexandre/Documents/developpement/piemapping/apple-pie/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js!/Users/alexandre/Documents/developpement/piemapping/apple-pie/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js!/Users/alexandre/Documents/developpement/piemapping/apple-pie/src/scripts/main.jsx Line 12: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| // Imports
| import React from "react";
| import Dispatcher from "./Dispatcher.js";
```

Without webpack i am running this command which is working great :

```
"lint": "eslint . --ext .js --ext .jsx --fix"
```

I would like that webpack check my code at compile time and compile or not depending if eslint raise an error or not.